# Oracle Apex button click it will open new window

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Oracle Apex 5.1, once click the button it will open new window its possible?, any one please provide the sample code

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.:::1:P1_ID:'+$v("P844_ID")+','_blank');

Answer (score 2):

In dynamic action : create an on click DA that executes JS

```
var rowid= this.triggeringElement.id;
vUrl = apex.util.makeApplicationUrl({
//appId: $v("pFlowId"),                   // default is $v("pFlowId") - current app
pageId:10,                     // default is $v("pFlowStepId") - current page
//session: $v( "pInstance" ),   // default is $v("pInstance") - current session
// request: 'TEST_REQUEST',      // default is $v("pRequest") - current request
//debug: 'YES',                 // default is $v("pdebug") - debug YES/NO
itemNames:['P10_SHP_APPLICATIONS_TBL_ROWID'],        
// item names array (no value by default)
itemValues:[rowid]      // item values array (no value by default)
  //printerFriendly: 'YES'        // no value by default 
});//console.log(vUrl);
window.open(vUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

LMGTFY - Did you try the following

[APEX open URL in new window](http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/opening-url-in-new-window/)

Comment: Use the below code it will help to redirect another new tab

javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.:::1:P1_ID:'+$v("P844_ID")+','_blank');

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:3002:&SESSION.:::3002:P3002_CPY_ID,P3002_RPM_ID,P3002_ACM_ID,    P3002_FORMAT,P3002_REPORT_PAGE_NO:'+$v("P1977_CPY_ID")+','+$v("P1977_RPM_ID")+','+$v("P1977_ACM_ID")+',VIEW,1977','_blank');
```

Use the above code 
Click the button and create the dynamic action and select Execute Js and paste the query.. pass the parameter and page no everything.. then try

Answer (score 0):

Flow below step

```
Go to Button
Go to button Behavior
Action : Redirect to URL
javascript:window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.::NO:1:P1_PID:'+$v("P2_PID")+'');
```